# Packaging Multiple Python Files

Tags: python-3.x, packaging, deb, software-packaging

I currently am using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399552/how-to-create-a-deb-package-for-a-python3-script#) to package up my project [wasp](https://github.com/devinmatte/wasp). However currently everything lives inside of the `wasp` file.

That's not ideal. I would rather have all the classes in separate files so it can be more effectively managed. I have the series of files needed in the [debian](https://github.com/devinmatte/wasp/tree/master/debian) directory. But I'm not sure how to configure the packaging to package multiple files.

Is there a way to change my packaging to package more than just the one script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a debian package or Python expert, but one way would be to copy the various source files to another location (outside of /usr/bin), and then have /usr/bin/wasp call out to them.

Say you put all of your python code in `src/` in the root of your repo. In the `debian/install` file, you'd have:

```
wasp usr/bin
src/* usr/lib/wasp/
```

You'd then  just need `/usr/bin/wasp` to call some entry point in `src`. For example,

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/wasp/')

import wasp # or whatever you expose in src

# ...
```

Again, I don't know the best practices here (either in directory or python usage) but I think this would at least work!